# MailChimp API V2 Need Help Regarding Templates

Tags: api, templates, mailchimp

I am using the REST based MailChimp API version 2.0. I am trying to create a campaign using the campaigns/create API method. I have a template that I designed using the built in designer. In the request I specify the template ID of this template when creating the campaign. Is there a way I can send html in the body of the template while creating the campaign using the API ?. I have tried the following code, it works however I am unable to put in my custom html in the template when creating the campaign

```
{
    "apikey": "my_key",
    "type": "regular",
    "options": {
        "list_id": "d1c5306a1f",
        "subject": "Welcome",
        "from_email": "my@email.com",
        "from_name": "Fawad Rashid",
        "to_name": "Subscriber",
        "template_id": 94425,
        "inline_css": true,
        "generate_text": true
    },
    "content": {
        "html": "example html",
        "sections": {
            "text": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly guide me in this regards

Comment: A quick update, I was able to get the content in the editable content area by creating a custom template of my own rather than using a pre-built template that comes bundled in mailchimp. It would be very good if there is a way to use the pre-built templates to accommodate custom html